How can I change regions in 'apphosting.yaml' in Firebase App Hosting
I can't find a way to set a different region for App Hosting. It's not in firebase console and I can't find any examples to configure the apphosting.yaml file
I deployed my web app using apphosting and it was deployed to us-central1 and I want to deploy to australia-southeast1

Firebase App Hosting is currently only supports us-central1, new regions are coming soon. That is when you will be able to choose different regions.
